# Defining 'step' attribute in Zingchart renders the graph unusable

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, zingchart

**Scenario:**

I am able to get a status graph with Zingchart, using a *stacked hbar* and plotting data intervals where the status of an element doesn't change:
[image: Zingchart graph OK]

However, I would like to have more resolution in the axis that provides the time.

**Problem:**

I am not able to increase the number of *ticks* in the `y-axis` (this is an stacked *hbar* graph, so the usual `x-axis` is actually the `y-axis`).

If I introduce `step:"1hour",` in the `scaleY` field I get back to epoch 0 and this is what I obtain:

[image: Zingchart graph definitely not OK]

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong? I would like either:

- To have more time references in the axis of the time.
- Or (and this may be another question) to be able to know *on mouse over* (in the tooltip?) at what time I am. Since I am plotting time increments I lost the *actual time* on where the change of status happens. Is there a direct way to do this in this particular situation? Or do I have to carry another `data-customValue` for the actual date of the start / end of the interval?

In the code, I *jump* from epoch 0 to the time I start having data, and define `minValue` to plot as the first epoch I have data minus one second. 
This is the working code (no `step` attribute defined):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="/home/eballes/Work/backup/zingchart_test/zingchart_2.3.3/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    zingchart.MODULESDIR = "/home/eballes/Work/backup/zingchart_test/zingchart_2.3.3/modules/";
  </script>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
  <script>
var myConfig = {
    type: "hbar",
    utc:true,
    title: {
      text: 'Status'
    },
    scaleY:{
      transform:{
        type:'date',
        all:"%d/%M/%Y\n%H:%i:%s",
      },
      minValue:1456693864000, 
      zooming:true,
      label:{
        "text": "Time",
      },
      tick:{
          "line-color":"black",
          "line-width":"2px",
          "size":8,
      },
      maxItems:10,
      itemsOverlap:true,
      item:{
        "font-size":10
      },
    },
    scaleX:{
      label:{
        "text": "Item",
      },
    },
    plot:{
      stacked:true,
      exact:false,
      barWidth:10,
      rules:[
        {
          rule:'%data-customValue == 0',
          alpha:0, // Transparent
        },
        {
          rule:'%data-customValue == 1',
          backgroundColor:'#0000FF' // Dark Blue
        },
        {
          rule:'%data-customValue == 2',
          backgroundColor:'#00FFFF' // Light Blue
        },
        {
          rule:'%data-customValue == 3',
          backgroundColor:'#FF7F50' // Orange
        },
        {
          rule:'%data-customValue == 4',
          backgroundColor:'#FFFF00' // Yellow
        },
        {
          rule:'%data-customValue == 5',
          backgroundColor:'#EE82EE' // Purple
        },
        {
          rule:'%data-customValue == 6',
          backgroundColor:'#00FF00' // Green
        },
        {
          rule:'%data-customValue == 7',
          backgroundColor:'#FF0000' // Red
        },
      ]
    },
    tooltip:{
        jsRule:"CustomFn.formatTooltip()",
    },
    series : [
        {
            values : [
            [1,1456693864000],
            [2,1456693864000], 
            .... // From 1 to 36
            [36,1456693864000], 
            ],
            'data-customValue':[0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,0],
        },
                {
            values : [
[11, 32000], [12, 10270000], [14, 5033000], [18, 79000], [20, 43000], [24, 76000], [26, 4043000], [8, 33000], [9, 63000], 
            ],
            'data-customValue':[2, 6, 6, 0, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, ],
        },
        {
            values : [
[14, 3000], [19, 20000], [26, 1000], [8, 86000], [9, 13000], 
            ],
            'data-customValue':[2, 2, 2, 0, 1, ],
        },
// All intervals

    ]
};

CustomFn = {};
CustomFn.formatTooltip = function(p){
  var hours = Math.floor(p.value / 3600000);
  var minutes = Math.floor((p.value % 3600000) / 60000);
  var seconds = (p.value % 60000)/1000;
  var tooltipText = "Item: " + p.scaletext + "\nDuration: ";

  var hoursText = (hours == 0) ? "" : (hours + "h ");
  var minutesText = (minutes == 0) ? "" : (minutes + "m");
  var secondsText = (seconds == 0) ? "" : (seconds + "s");

  tooltipText = tooltipText + hoursText + minutesText + secondsText + "\n";
  tooltipText = tooltipText + "Value: " + p['data-customValue'];

  var alpha = 70;

  // We don't want any tooltip for the time-jump
  if (hours > 300000) {
    tooltipText = "";
    alpha = 0;
  }

  return {
    text : tooltipText,
    backgroundColor : "#222",
    alpha: alpha,
  }
};

zingchart.render({
    id : 'myChart',
    data : myConfig,
    height: 670,
    width: '100%'
});
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the link to the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wt8InAhXGF1Dh1HB9YLO) with the whole example, not working. If you remove the line `step:"1hour"`, it will work.

Funny enough, `step:20` works fine. But I would prefer to have my steps in a *normal* way, like hourly.

---

*Note*: Just to provide some more context, this question is the continuation of this other [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837185/multiplot-and-change-line-color-depending-on-column-value-in-zingchart) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full Disclosure, I'm a member of the ZingChart team.

The first problem being

```
step:'1hour'
```

That string value is being interpreted by our library as the value 0. This is because the string '1hour' does not match any of our keywords nor does it evaluate to a Number type. We are not simply using parseInt so it does not evaluate to 1.

If you want an hourly step you would do the step count in milliseconds. This is documented in our [scales page](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/basic-elements/configure-chart-scales/#scale-types-time-series-scale).

```
step:3600000
```

For display the scale value we do have a [tokens](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/basic-elements/zingchart-tokens/) list which allows you to add values from your scale to your tooltip. In your customFn.formatTooltip you would add this line.

```
  ...
  tooltipText = tooltipText + "Value: " + p['data-customValue'];
  tooltipText += '<br> %vv'
```

The `%vv` is in our [tokens](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/basic-elements/zingchart-tokens/) list and will grab the transformed value off the y-axis. If you did `%vt` it would give you the millisecond value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great. However I see the documentation a bit misleading regarding `step`. We can see several examples with  `"step":"30minute", //Step Value` and the documentation says: "We created the following shorthand values that you can use in lieu of timestamps when calculating your step. You can add a multiplier to any of these terms." This list of shorthand values includes `hour`, so I would expect `step:'1hour'` to work.